# Updating only the submitted fields from account settings page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an account settings page which will detect any changed fields and submit those fields via jquery.ajax to a php file, the php file intakes it and validates each field on some different cases and if any of them throw an error it returns the error, exits, and requires user to reinput the field.  That all works fine... however...

I'm having my problem with how to build a loop to only update the submitted fields.  Currently the php file has this structure:

```
Check for ajax request {
   Validate fields...
   Update Fields...
}
```

My "Update Fields" code looks like this and *yes* it won't work this way, I know:

```
// grab all variables except passwords
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$newpass = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['newpass']));
$bname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bname']);
$bemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bemail']);
$sql = "UPDATE usertable SET email='$email', password='$newpass', bname='$bname', bemail='$bemail'  WHERE username = '$user'";
mysql_query($sql);  
$msg = "Account updated successfully."; 

            header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
            header('Expires: '.date('r', time()+(86400*365)));
            header('Content-type: application/json');

            echo json_encode(array(
                'valid' => yes,
                'msg' => $msg,
            ));
            exit();
```

The line in question is the $sql = "Update usertable..." line.  How can I write a php loop to grab all the posted variables as an array and somehow use those to build an update query string... if you need anything else let me know.  Asking a lot, but I've been thinking for four hours and can't figure out a way to do it without lots of run around non-direct coding.

Also: Is there a way to return ALL the unvalidated fields?  General idea, such as using an array and for each loop or something?  Currently if let's say, the email field and password field don't validate, it only shows the email field as needing to be re-entered because it shows up first in the php file.  I would prefer it to tell them ALL the fields that didn't validate.  I know it just had to do with the position of my code and the way I'm just hand coding each validation (which is the long way) so any insight into this will help me a BILLION especially with future pages on the backend.

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only update the fields which are within the `$_POST` array and defined in `$fieldsToUpdate` (So you can exclude fields):

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$fieldsToUpdate = array('email', 'bname','bemail');
$set = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(in_array($key,$fieldsToUpdate)){
        $set[] = $key."='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
    }
}

if(count($set) > 0){
    $query = "UPDATE usertable SET ".implode(',',$set)." WHERE username = '$user'";
    // rest of your code;
}
```

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated, think about using `PDO`

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would go about taking in the serialized string from the ajax request (of all the edited fields) and break it down into an array of fields to udpate?  Other than that, this seems like it will work great for what I need...

Also, what about building a list of responses so that it can say "This this and this were updated, this was not updated"?  Or should I just not submit anything if something needs validation and only update submitted fields when ALL fields validate if multiple fields were edited?

Selected your answer as well, thank you for that!!!